# How to Force Nvidia Driver Usage on Lenovo P1?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, laptop, lenovo

My brand new [Lenovo P1](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p1-gen-2-type-20qt-20qu/documentation) cannot use an external display with Ubuntu 18.04. I suspect my problem is that I am using the built in display drivers. Any idea what needs to be done to use the Nvidia driver to access the external display?

Comment: Did you check the UEFI Setings/BIOS for video related items. Sometimes you have to explicitly choose discrete (vs integrated) to use the Nvidia and external monitor.

Comment: I don't know how to check the UEFI Setting/BIOS. Can you help with that? Unix was installed on the laptop by the IT admins.

Comment: Some function key or esc or del key at power-up (f12 on my lenovo, or the blue "thinkvantage) button.  Try reading the splash screen, if one comes up, it might identify which button. Set boot speed to something other than 0 or fast to give yourself more time to press a button (once you get in). Grub boot might offer a setup choice. Windows restart with shift key held down gets you into a menu system next boot which eventually gets to UEFI settings.

Comment: I was able to get into the bios and select discrete vs integrated. Still cannot even get the FN-F7 or F7 by itself to to anything. Also when I check the details now Ubuntu reports the discrete graphics as llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits). I was expecting to see nvidia here.

Comment: Additonal note: I tried running nvidia-smi but received an error message saying it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem with help from everyone. I had to:

- Install the Nvidia drivers
- Disable secure boot (this allowed me to now run nvidia-smi)
- I am using a HDMI to VGA adaptor; I had to supply power to the adaptor and then everything worked

Comment: Another notice: If you want to switch between Nvidia and Intel Cards, use `sudo prime-select <card name>`, where card name is `nvidia` or `intel`